# Disable ListView Scrolls

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, android-linearlayout

I'm running into a problem and i can't figure out how to implement it. I have many controls in my Linear layout and a Listview. Because I have many controls controls in my screen so i hadto implement scrolls in my layout BUT after i get through the listview it again has its scrolls so i have 2 scrolls in my screen. My question is how to disable the ListView scrolls and view all it's cells in the screen so that the user can scroll from the main scrollview.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv;
lv.canScrollVertically(0);
```